# JavaScript 1e16 * Math.random() equivalente a PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo esta linea de código que al ejecutarla en la consola genera números aleatorios de 16 caracteres:

```
1e16 * Math.random()
```

Al ejecutar puede dar esta clase de resultados:

```
1e16 * Math.random() //8988522134496624
```

Como se puede ver genera el número de 16 dígitos.
Mi pregunta es, como puedo lograr esto en PHP?

por ahora tengo esto y nada que funciona:

```
function random() {
   return rand(1e16, 100000000000000) / 1e16;
}
echo random();
```

// este es el error

> Warning: rand() expects parameter 1 to be integer, float given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\prueba.php on line 3 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que las pruebas las estaba haciendo en XAMPP me daba ese error que escribí arriba, la solución sin tanto código es:

```
<?php
 $random = rand(1e16, 100000000000000);
 echo $random; //8988522134496624
<?
```

Comment: XAMPP no tiene nada que ver, esta solución y tu código de la pregunta no son lo mismo. Y por otra parte, no siempre una solución es mejor porque tenga menos código.

Comment: Solo digo que hice las pruebas en XAMPP y me salia error y cuando hice la prueba en mi hosting no salia el error, creo que fui muy claro.

Answer (score 4):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo.

Por ejemplo:

#### Combinando `rand` y `pow`

```
$digits = 16;
echo rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
```

***Salida:***

```
4532665451057255
```

#### Combinando `mt_rand` y `pow`

```
$digits = 16;
echo mt_rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
```

***Salida:***

```
2518521800171584
```

#### Usando un bucle `for`

```
function randomNumber($length) {
    $result = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $result .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }
    return $result;
}
echo randomNumber(16);
```

***Salida:***

```
1033651704719868
```

Para más detalles puedes ver [esta respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8215979/5587982)

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
function random() {
   return rand(100000000000000,1e16);
}
echo random();

function random_16d() {
  $rand   = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i<15; $i++) {
    $rand .= mt_rand(0,9);
  }
 return $rand;
}

echo random_16d()
```

Comment: y la explicacion?